# How do i unregister broadcast receiver in this code?

Tags: android

I have dynamically registered my broadcast receiver , now how do i unregister it . i have used unregisterReceiver(this). but i dont think it works.

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SENT");

       //---when the SMS has been sent---
       registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
               switch (getResultCode())
               {
                   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent waiting room", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      unregisterReceiver(this); 
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Network Detected", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
               }
           }
       }, filter);
```

Comment: You have to call unregisterReceiver() with the same instance that you registered with

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
unregisterReceiver(nameofyourbroadcastreceiver);
```

Sample Code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SomeBroadcastReceiver();

  public void onResume()
  {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);  

  }

  public void onPause()
  {
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```

Your code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SENT");

BroadcastReceiver br =  new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {

        switch (getResultCode())
           {
               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent waiting room", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  unregisterReceiver(br); 
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
               case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Network Detected", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   break;
           }

    }
};

registerReceiver (br, filter);
```

Comment: you created an anonymous function. Create a broadcast receiver object (global), register receiver and un-register it when you want to with my code above.

Comment: i am trying to create a gloabl object something like 
BroadcastReceiver obj = new BroadCastReceiver();
it doesnot works

Comment: in my code i want that as soon as the "RESULT_OK" case comes. the broadcast receiver should unregister

Comment: my friend, create a broadcastreceiver like I mentioned above and pass that reference where you want to unregister.

Comment: Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: oh yeah ....that helped ... unfortunately i lack karma to upvote your answer...thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

in [public abstract void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/content/Context.java#Context.registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%2Candroid.content.IntentFilter%29)
you must provide a `BroadcastReceiver` instance as the first parament.

you can write like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver(){
...
}

unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

---